# Simple, plug-and-play live USB instalation , step-by-step?

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

I need a simple and **secure** way to generate a pendrive for Stable Debian,

> https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/index.en.html#write-usb
>    (FAQ confuse, it is not only a `cp` command)

but how to do step-by-step?

I need copy something, where and how to copy from wget to my pendrive directly?

Looking for plug-and-play I see http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html
bot it is secure?  There are no simple way to do a copy on my pendrive?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, secure is "no troia", no problems, stable, etc.

Comment: OK, well secure to some implies some sort of security issue, I suggest foolproof or similar term.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Debian is *unfortunately* off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks @Fabby, in next opportunity I will use Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not secure.

To securely install unetbootin, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Alternatively, you can use the cat command like so to copy the **.iso** file to the usb device:

```
sudo -s
cat <file> > <device>
exit
```

or you can use the dd command:

```
sudo dd if=<file> of=<device> bs=4M; sync
```

but I think cat is faster.

---

To determine your `<device>`, run the following command:

```
lsblk
```

All of your devices will be listed. Inspect the list to determine which device is your hard drive (/dev/sda most likely) and which device is your usb device (/dev/sdc or /dev/sdb or something else). **Be careful, however,** because if you cat to the wrong device, you will overwrite all the files on that device. **Measure twice, cut once!**

---

**EDIT**

I do not recommend you use wget to do the download as wget will not reassume the download if you get disconnected. You should use aria2c instead.

First, install aria2c:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Next, to do the download:

```
aria2c http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-netins‌​t.iso
```

for a "live image", use one of the links from the following page:

http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/

example (for xfce):

```
aria2c http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-xfce-desktop.iso
```

aria2 has the ability to resume failed or interrupted downloads.

Comment: Thanks! I will use unetbootin.. The  pendrive is at  `/dev/sdc1`... Well, abou download ISO ... where the "debian stable iso for pendrive"?, there are a `wget` command to do this download? it is at https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/  ?

Comment: PS: I am at Ubuntu and need to format it later, after sucess-tests on LiveLinux

Comment: @PeterKrauss do you want an image to install to your computer from or do you need a "live" version you can use to test it out without installing to your harddrive?

Comment: @PeterKrauss for larger downloads, I recommend using aria2c instead of wget. I updated the answer to include those instructions.

Comment: Thanks, `unetbootin` (your apt-get) with `debian-live-8.1.0-amd64-xfce-desktop.iso`  works fine! Now I testing all by Live pendrive debian... Only later, after tests, I will install Stable Debian

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create bootable install media for Debian, from a Debian installation, UNetBootIn is fine. I don't know what you mean by "secure" or "do a copy."

Also, this is an Ubuntu Q&A site. Debian, while similar, is not Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, about "secure" I am thinking on "troia" and NSA, etc. malware.  About Debian: I am using Ubuntu but need a "secure and stable" partition.